# disable snap drag behaviour in Angularjs Snap to avoid the conflict with ng Grid drag for grouping functionality

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my Angularjs application, I am using Angular Snap (http://jtrussell.github.io/angular-snap.js/) and Angularjs ng Grid together. In ng Grid, I need to provide Grouping functionality for which I need to drag the column header to the top most row ((http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/) - Grouping example . But when I am dragging the header in NgGrid, instead ng Grid drag functionality, Angular snap drag functionality is getting fired. How can I disable drag feature in Angular snap. Angular snap should work only with snap toggle button click not with drag feature. Or is there any way that ng Grid drag can override the snap drag behavior?

Answer (score 0):

In ng Grid Options set  jqueryUIDraggable to false.

```
$scope.gridOptions = { 
                                          ...
                                            jqueryUIDraggable: false,
                                           ....
                                        };
```